# DSN of various databases in PDO

Tags: php, database, pdo, helper

I am creating a helper class and adding in a PDO instance into it.
I want the class method to be able to connect to various databases.
What is the best way to go around it?
So far I have:

```
    public static function connect($dbType, $database, $host, $username,
    $password, $options = array())
{
    switch($dbType)
    {
        case "pgsql":
            $DSN = "pgsql:dbname=$database;host=$host";
            break;

        case "mysql":
            $DSN = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";
            break;

        case .....
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to perform this without the need to detect the $dbType over and over?
Is there a more dynamic way to do it?

Comment: It is not a class if all your methods are static. It's a namespaces which just looks like a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't see the need to provision for so many databases, because PDO doesn't abstract out the intricate query language differences and capabilities of each driver :)

Having said that, you could create a function to just generate the DSN:

```
function generateDSN($type, array $params)
{
    return "$type:" . join(';', array_map(function($v, $k) {
        return "$k=$v";
    }, $params, array_keys($params)));
}

echo generateDSN('mysql', array(
        'dbname' => 'test',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
));

mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8
```

Comment: Why thanks for the help! I am now reading articles about helper classes and seems like I will refrain away from ever using statics!
I will implement you code instead.
Thanks again :) 

P.S. Urahara Jack san... (couldn't help it)